# How to get the coordinates of the pin/marker using ESRI and JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, esri, arcgis-js-api

I have this JavaScript code that allows me to drop a pin/marker on to a map. Now I want to get the coordinates of the dropped pin. How do I do that? Please see code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no" />
    <title>APPLICATION</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/esri/themes/light/main.css" />
    <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.12/"></script>

    <style>
        html,
        body,
        #viewDiv {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        require([
            "esri/widgets/Sketch",
            "esri/Map",
            "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer",
            "esri/views/MapView"
        ], function (Sketch, Map, GraphicsLayer, MapView) {
            const layer = new GraphicsLayer();

            const map = new Map({
                basemap: "streets",
                layers: [layer]
            });

            const view = new MapView({
                container: "viewDiv",
                map: map,
                zoom: 5,
                center: [90, 45]
            });

            const sketch = new Sketch({
                layer: layer,
                view: view,
                availableCreateTools: ["point"]
            });

            view.ui.add(sketch, "top-right");

            sketch.on('create', function (evt) {
                console.info(evt.graphic.geometry);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Please assist. I can see the map and drop a pin, but I also need to get the coordinates of that pin.

Answer (score 2):

You can access the coordinates from the graphic (pin) geometry:

Here you can access it after the sketch is created:

```
sketch.on('create', function (evt) {
  console.info(evt.graphic.geometry);
  var x = evt.graphic.geometry.x;
  var y = evt.graphic.geometry.y;
});
```

Here you access it from the graphicLayer in which the sketches are stored:

```
layer.graphics.forEach(function(graphic) {
  var x = graphic.geometry.x;
  var y = graphic.geometry.y;
});
```

Comment: No problem Siya!

Comment: Hi Below the Radar, is it possible to change the color of the point that I dropped on the map?

Comment: Yes, but please create a new question for this issue